# How to intentionally ignore subquery of a filter in Hibernate Search?

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I will try describe the problem.
Lets assume we have lucene document with fields TITLE, DESC, TYPE. 
Now I do search by this fields like this:

```
org.​apache.​lucene.​search.Query titleQuery = prepareTitleQuery();
org.​apache.​lucene.​search.Query descQuery = prepareDescQuery();
org.​apache.​lucene.​search.Query mainQuery = queryBuilder.bool().should(titleQuery).should(descQuery).createQuery()
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(mainQuery, Class.class);
fullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter("typeFilter").setParameter("types", types);
```

This is very simplified code, just to give overall understanding what I'm doing.

Now example:

```
TITLE | DESC | TYPE 
Some title | hibernate search | 1
Another title | lucene | 1, 3
Something here | search lucene | 2, 8, 3
```

I search like this:

```
TITLE:Another
DESC:lucene
TYPE:1
```

It will find only second line. But I need third line two. Is there any way to make filter applied only to `titleQuery`, but not to `descQuery`? Also I have another filters and sorting that should apply to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filters are applied on the overall search result. They are not applied to parts of a composed query. I guess your best is to write the title query as a boolean query itself, composed of two parts - one for matching the title and one for matching the type. As far as I understand this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Finally I came to this myself.
This is what I did:

`for (Type type : types) {`
                `titleQuery = queryBuilder.bool().must(titleQuery).must(queryBuilder.keyword().onField("types.id").matching(type.getId()).createQuery()).createQuery();`
            `}`